# compiz and Xorg take too much CPU ubuntu17.04

Tags: xorg, compiz, cpu

I newly install the ubuntu desktop, but I found the compiz and xorg take too much resource all the time.

From the top command,

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND            
 1892 roofe     20   0 1579044 287380  85836 S  78.1  1.8  39:43.87 compiz             
 1050 root      20   0  681628 212636  75664 S  22.6  1.3  11:25.04 Xorg
```

and lspci,

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port #17 (rev f1)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
04:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 04)
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation Device f1a5 (rev 03)
```

Comment: Oh yes, compiz is a monster! However, by instralling the recommended Nvidia drivers for the graphics card you will notice a great improvement.

Comment: @MichaelBay Thanks. Can you show me how to make it.

Comment: Just open Additional Drivers, wait a few moments, then selct and apply the recommended version. Reboot.

Comment: And after I apply the nvidia driver, I found the icon in the launcher also can customized the icon size. The icon size cannot be changed when newly installed the OS, when I set the size, but nothing changed.